# T-sql count number of times a week on rows with date interval

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

If you have table like this:

| Name | Data type |
| --- | --- |
| UserID | INT |
| StartDate | DATETIME |
| EndDate | DATETIME |

With data like this:

| UserID | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 21 | 2021-01-02 00:00:00 | 2021-01-02 23:59:59 |
| 21 | 2021-01-03 00:00:00 | 2021-01-04 15:42:00 |
| 24 | 2021-01-02 00:00:00 | 2021-01-06 23:59:59 |

And you want to calculate number of users that is represented on each day in a week with a result like this:

| Year | Week | NumberOfTimes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 1 | 8 |
| 2021 | 2 | 10 |
| 2021 | 3 | 4 |

Basically I want to to a Select like this:

```
SELECT YEAR(dateColumn) AS yearname, WEEK(dateColumn)as week name, COUNT(somecolumen)
GROUP BY YEAR(dateColumn) WEEK(dateColumn)
```

The problem I have is the start and end date if the date goes over several days I want it to counted each day. Preferably I don't want the same user counted twice each day. There are millions of rows that are constantly being deleted and added so speed is key.

The database is MS-SQL 2019

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select userid, startdate, enddate
      from t
      union all
      select userid, startdate,
             enddate
      from cte
      where startdate < enddate and
            week(startdate) <> week(enddate)
     )
select year(startdate), week(startdate), count(*)
from cte
group by year(startdate), week(startdate)
option (maxrecursion 0);
```

The CTE expands the data by adding 7 days to each row.  This should be one day per week.

There is a little logic in the second part to handle the situation where the `enddate` ends in the same week as the last start date.  The above solution assumes that the dates are all in the same year -- which seems quite reasonable given the sample data.  There are other ways to prevent this problem.

Comment: Basically you want to input a start and endate for the period you want it calculated. It can go over years.

I've tried the above but get an error message saying: The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.

Comment: @Addeladde . . . The `option` fixes that issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cross-join each row with the relevant dates.

Create a calendar table with columns of years and weeks, include a start and end date of the week. [See here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) for an example of how to create one, and make sure you index those columns.

Then you can cross-join like this

```sql
SELECT
    YEAR(dateColumn) AS yearname,
    WEEK(dateColumn)as weekname,
    COUNT(somecolumen)
FROM Table t
JOIN CalendarWeek c ON c.StartDate >= t.StartDate AND c.EndDate <= t.EndDate
GROUP BY YEAR(dateColumn), WEEK(dateColumn)
```